# Oracle SQL thinks it's the year 1909, not 2009

Tags: sql, oracle

This is figure 10-41 from the Casteel 12c SQL textbook.

The book has an example which run on my local SQL developer returns the wrong number of years as it believes the query is for 1909, not 2009.

```
select empno, lname, fname,hiredate,
    ROUND(MONTHS_BETWEEN(hiredate, '01-JUL-09')/12,2) "Years",
    case
        when (months_between('01-JUL-09', hiredate)/12) < 4 then 'Level 1'
        when (months_between('01-JUL-09', hiredate)/12) < 8 then 'Level 2'
        when (months_between('01-JUL-09', hiredate)/12) < 11 then 'Level 3'
        when (months_between('01-JUL-09', hiredate)/12) < 15 then 'Level 4'
        else 'Level 5'
    end "Retire Level"
from employees;
```

Returns in the range 82 to 89 years (to 2 decimal places) but in the textbook, it shows a return value range of 10 to 17 years because it's properly doing the math for 2009.

So I changed it to `2009` but get the same result:

```
select empno, lname, fname,hiredate,
    ROUND(MONTHS_BETWEEN(hiredate, '01-JUL-2009')/12,2) "Years",
    case
        when (months_between('01-JUL-2009', hiredate)/12) < 4 then 'Level 1'
        when (months_between('01-JUL-2009', hiredate)/12) < 8 then 'Level 2'
        when (months_between('01-JUL-2009', hiredate)/12) < 11 then 'Level 3'
        when (months_between('01-JUL-2009', hiredate)/12) < 15 then 'Level 4'
        else 'Level 5'
    end "Retire Level"
from employees;
```

How do I tell SQL that it's 2009 for the months_between calculation?

Comment: I'm very skeptical of your claim that Oracle is interpreting `'01-JUL-2009'` as 1 July 1909. Can you produce a [minimal, self-contained query](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates this behavior?

Comment: @ruakh, the figure number from the textbook is listed.  I'm on the SQL developer VM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*How do I tell SQL that it's 2009 for the months_between calculation?*

Be specific (don't rely on default interpretation of date literals), use `DATE` or `TO_DATE()` e.g.

```
DATE '2009-07-01'
TO_DATE('01-JUL-2009','dd-mmm-yyyyy')
```

`DATE` requires a YYYY-MM-DD literal. whereas `TO_DATE()` allows you you specify the literal pattern to use. See [Date Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#sthref364)

ps: Personally I dislike using spoken language dependent date literals, or 2 digit year references

Answer (score 0):

Try converting your string dates to actual dates with `TO_DATE` ex. `TO_DATE('01-JUL-2009', 'dd-MON-YYYY')`

Answer (score 0):

With two-digit years, you can use the RR date format, so 00 to 49 are taken as the current century (and 50 to 99 are the next century), so :

```
TO_DATE('01-JUL-09', 'DD-MON-RR')
```

See :
http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/Format-Models.htm#GUID-6C75461E-2E18-4C35-9EB4-038A7E1C9C1F

Also, a bit outside my knowledge area, but I think you can set this date format as the default using NLS_DATE_FORMAT , so do a search on that term - eg

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams122.htm#REFRN10119